# I need to rewrite a rule to delete the category id from the url - nginx

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I am creating a custom ecommerce application with url of product catlog as

```
https://www.example.com/cat-title/cat-id
```

I want to delete the id from the url

```
https://www.example.com/cat-id
```

I have tried something like this below

```
rewrite ^(/category/[^/]+/). $1 redirect;
```

Comment: Can you add your full server block configuration if possible?

Comment: You want to delete the id or the title? What didn't the `rewrite` meet your requirements? Please add access log entries and the result of `curl -I https://www.example.com/cat-title/cat-id` to your question.

Comment: @RichardSmith sir, i want to know if i there's a way to get `cat-id` after rewriting the url via nginx ???